# About COBOL OPEN command. Does it "lock" files/PDSes?

Tags: locking, cobol, mainframe

So I have this online program that writes data on a PDS member (used/accessed by other programs too).

Does the OPEN command in COBOL "locks" the PDS for exclusive use kinda like IBM's ENQ/DEQ utility? So that other programs cant write on it while I'm using it? Im in mainframe zOS btw.

I already tested but I'm kind of skeptical with my test setup. Which is...

```
JCL > COBOL01 > COBOL02
```

... where COBOL01 opens the PDS, calls COBOL02 which opens the same PDS, then WRITE on it. Result was COBOL02 can't write on the PDS.

But that's on a single call chain, what if it's an online transaction?

Answer (score 1):

The ENQ is part of the file allocation, which in your case is happening as a result of the `status` subparameter of the `DISP` parameter on your `DD` statement in your JCL.

```
DISP=(status,normal-termination,abnormal-termination)
```

...or, alternatively...

```
DISP=status
```

If you code `DISP=OLD`, you have exclusive control of the dataset.  Check in the IBM Knowledge Center for differences between PDS and PDSE behavior.

The same applies for an online transaction, but your allocation may be done differently.  If you're running as part of an ISPF dialog, the allocation may be done via an `ALLOCATE` command.  If you're running in CICS then dynamic allocation may be done or, more commonly in your case of a PDS it may be done via the JCL for the CICS region.

You say you opened the PDS twice, are you certain the second open actually worked?  If you have a `FILE STATUS` clause coded, did you check the assigned data name?  Were there error messages in the `JESMSGLG`?

Answer (score 1):

I always like to dig a little deeper in these types of questions in the hope that some might appreciate the parts of mainframe operating system design that are sometimes difficult to see from the outside...

As you surmise, at the core of "locking", you'll find the z/OS ENQ/DEQ system services. These functions provide a simple way to serialize just about any resource, and there are always two parameters: a "QNAME" and an "RNAME". The QNAME identifies the class of resources...in your example, it would be SYSDSN - a dataset enqueue. The RNAME is the resource name, and in your example, it would be the actual dataset name (not including the member name, if the dataset is a PDS).

As cschneid explains above, when you allocate a conventional mainframe dataset, the system allocation routines issue ENQ on SYSDSN with the dataset name, and either SHARED or EXCLUSIVE access, depending on whether you coded DISP=SHR or something else in your allocation. If there's a conflict (that is, you requested SHARED, but another task has EXCLUSIVE), the ENQ fails and you'll see a message on the console about your task "WAITING FOR DATASETS". Otherwise, the allocation proceeds, and the ENQ protects you according to the DISP you specified in your JCL.

There are a few other situations to think about...

PDS datasets are a little unusual because the ENQ is at the full dataset level, not the member level. This means there's generally no way to lock an individual member - the lock is at the level of the full dataset. Applications like the ISPF editor try to get around this by creating their own ENQs on a different resource. The ISPF editor uses QNAME=SYSISPF with an RNAME that includes a member name to detect two users editing the same member name at the same time, but this only provides protection between ISPF users, not an ISPF user and another application outside of ISPF.

VSAM has it's own notion of sharing that are controlled by the VSAM SHAREOPTIONS set when the VSAM file is defined. This makes the type of sharing a function of the file, rather than the application allocating the file.

ENQ can be single-system or can be across multiple systems. The system GRS (Global Resource Sharing) service is normally configured to propagate SYSDSN ENQs across all systems that might have physical access to the dataset.

Note that in the ENQ I described, there's no disk volume information. That is, if you have a dataset called XYZ on two different volumes, allocating the dataset you'll generally be serializing BOTH of them, no matter which you allocate. This can be a feature or a problem, depending on how you look at it.

JCL allocation is a little different than dynamic allocation. With dynamic allocation, most applications aren't allowed to wait for resources, so if there's a conflict, your call to DYNALLOC fails with a "resource not available' return code. In JCL allocation, you normally just wait for the resource contention to clear, then your job runs.

There are a few popular vendor products that change this flow a bit...CA's MIM product, for instance, automatically detects ENQ conflicts and reschedules the waiting job for later execution when its resource become available. This improves overall system throughput since another task can run instead.

Sophisticated applications sometimes use the RESERVE/RELEASE service to serialize access to files. RESERVE is a hardware feature of most mainframe devices that in essence serializes I/O to a given device until a corresponding RELEASE. It usually requires low-level I/O programming, but it can be faster than ENQ/DEQ, especially in a setting where there are many systems sharing resources.

Most system performance monitors have a function that lets you see and monitor ENQ activity...you can learn a lot by watching the flow of ENQs and how the system handles conflicts.

Comment: Valerie, the QNAME for ISPF is SPFEDIT.

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr: thanks for the fact check...my mistake - we have a local mod that transforms the SPFEDIT QNAMES to SYSISPF because we do some odd things with cross-system ENQs that start with "SYS". Totally forgot about this - thanks!

Comment: ah yes those local mods! Always fun to forget.